# Prove that $Tr(M |\psi\rangle \langle\phi|)=\langle\phi| M |\psi\rangle$

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, solution-verification, trace

#### Question:

I am studying alone and I found p.76 of [this book](https://profmcruz.files.wordpress.com/2017/08/quantum-computation-and-quantum-information-nielsen-chuang.pdf) that: $Tr(M |\psi\rangle\langle\psi)=\langle\psi| M |\psi\rangle$.

I want to be sure that my understanding of the formula is correct by proving a more general expression: $Tr(M |\psi\rangle\langle\phi|)=\langle\phi| M |\psi\rangle$, with $M$ an operator is correct.

#### Answer:

1- We [know](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Trace_(linear_algebra)) that $Tr(A) = \sum_i \lambda_i$, with $\lambda_i$ all the eigenvalues of $A$. Hence with $|i\rangle$ the eigenvector associated to the eigenvalue $\lambda_i$ we can write that $Tr(A) = \sum_i \langle i|A|i\rangle$ as $A|i\rangle=\lambda_i |i\rangle$.
*Rem:* To simplify the scripture I suppose that to each eigenvalue match only one eigenvector (I do not think that it will change a lot my demonstration in the case this is not the case).

2- By identifying $A=M |\psi\rangle \langle \phi|$ we can then write (with $|i\rangle$ the eigenvectors of $M |\psi\rangle \langle\phi|$), $Tr(M |\psi\rangle\langle\phi|)= \sum_i \langle i|M |\psi\rangle \langle \phi|i\rangle = \sum_i \langle \phi|i\rangle \langle i|M |\psi\rangle  = \langle \phi| (\sum_i |i\rangle \langle i| ) M |\psi\rangle $. The term $\sum_i |i\rangle \langle i| = I$ is the identity operator since it represents a sum over a complete set of projectors onto an orthonormal basis.

3- Hence we get $Tr(M |\psi\rangle \langle \phi|)=\langle \phi| M |\psi\rangle $

Is this correct? Did I forgot to write some conditions in order to make my prove more precise?

Comment: Why my question has been down voted?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

[Answer](https://quantumcomputing.stackexchange.com/questions/35781/prove-that-trm%CF%88%CF%95-%CF%95m%CF%88/35782#35782) by https://quantumcomputing.stackexchange.com/users/15795/pierre-paul-t

Your proof is not general, it assumes implicitly that the  operator $M|\psi\rangle\langle \phi|$ is diagonalizable (there is a basis of eigenvectors).

You can instead just use basic fact of Trace, namely $\mathrm{Tr}(AB)=\mathrm{Tr}(BA)$.

So
$\mathrm{Tr}(M|\psi\rangle\langle \phi|)=\mathrm{Tr}(\langle \phi|M|\psi\rangle)$

But $\langle \phi|M|\psi\rangle \in \mathbb{C}$ is just a scalar so

$\mathrm{Tr}(\langle \phi|M|\psi\rangle)=\langle \phi|M|\psi\rangle$

Comment: Wtf ? Why my answer had been down voted?